# In Django, how would you have an html page that lists all objects in the database with a common attribute?

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

First off, I'm a rookie on the field so if I miss out any necessary details, please do let me know and I'll update ASAP.

Working with Django framework and SQLite database, I would like to have two html pages that list all items with the same "type" attribute.

Right now models.py looks like this (there are more attributes after this, but that doesn't matter here, I think):

```
class Articulo(models.Model):
    MEDICINAL = 'med'
    AUTOCULTIVO = 'cul'
    TIPO_PROD = [
        (MEDICINAL, 'Medicinal'),
        (AUTOCULTIVO, 'Autocultivo'),
    ]
    tipo = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=TIPO_PROD,
        default=MEDICINAL,
        )
```

So I'd like for one of the html pages to list all the items with 'med' and another for all the items with 'cul'.

What I have tried is to write something similar to the search function to bring up those items by filtering that attribute, like this:

```
def medicinal(request):
    items = Articulo.objects.filter(tipo__icontains=med)
    return render(request, 'medicinales.html', {'articulos': articulos})
```

However, I'm really not sure how to continue from there.

I also want to add CSS to the list once it's displayed, but for that I will replicate the one I use for the search function, since I want them to retain the same style.

Thank you very much in advance and again, please let me know if I missed out some important information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use two views to do this, you can define one ListView, and then filter the data shown in the list by defining a `get_queryset` function in your view. Here is a quick example to give you an idea:

urls.py

```
path(r'list/', ArticuloListView.as_view(), name='articulo-list')
```

views.py

```
class ArticuloListView(ListView):
    model = Articulo
    context_object_name = 'articulos'
    template = 'artucilo_list.html' #this path may differ depending on your project structure

    def get_queryset(self):
        search_term = self.request.GET['q'] #'q' is defined in your search form
        return Articulo.objects.filter(tipo=search_term)
```

search template

```
...
<form action="{% url 'articulo-list' %}" method='GET'>
  <input name="q" type="text" value="{{ request.GET.q }}" placeholder="Search"/>
</form>
...
```

articulo_list.html template

```
...
{% for articulo in articulos %}
    {{ articulo.tipo }}
{% endfor %}
...
```

You dont have to filter based on a search form, you can also manually do it by using the querystring in a link href, like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'articulo-list' %}?q=med">Med List</a>
```

Comment: First, thank you for such a quick reply. I've been trying to work with it, with no luck.

I was able to allign the lines in urls.py and views.py with my project. In views.py I had to import the following:
`from django.views.generic.list import ListView`
I wasn't sure where the search form would go, so I went for the a href link. However, I'm getting a MultiValueDictKeyError with exception value 'med', or whatever is where 'q' would go. I suspect this is because I skipped the search form, so I tried placing it in 'medicinales.html' (where the 'med' list should go) but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it done by using a queryset as iri suggested, but in a simpler way.

In urls.py

```
path('medicinales/', productos_med, name='medicinales'),
```

In views.py:

```
def productos_med(request):
    queryset = Articulo.objects.filter(tipo='med')
    context = {
        "object_list": queryset
    }
    return render(request, "medicinales.html", context)
```

And in medicinales.html (the page with the list of all 'med' objects):

```
{% for instance in object_list %}
    <p>{{instance.nombre}}</p>
    <p>{{instance.descripcion}}</p> <!-- And so on for every wished attribute. -->
```

Then for objects with attribute 'cul' I followed the same steps changing tipo in queryset to 'cul' and rendering a different html page. After that applying CSS was easy!

Thank you very much iri for answering and pointing me in the right direction and the community for being such an awesome source of info!